# How do I create program launcher on Gnome classic desktop?

Tags: gnome, launcher

I am using the Gnome Classic desktop for my Ubuntu 12.04 PC. One of the thing that I am not able to do at the moment is placing program launchers (plus icon) on the desktop. I can create an item for the program on the 'Applications' menu but I prefer clicking on an icon on the desktop to launch a program. Anybody can give me pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Just drag and drop the item from the Applications menu onto the desktop or Gnome panel.

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Open nautilus.
2. Locate the file to launch.
3. Go to the file, click and hold with your left mouse button, press and hold the alt key, drag it to the desktop, release the mouse button, release the alt button, click 'Create shortcurt'.

Comment: Sorry but holding Alt + drag just 'moves' the whole window!

Comment: Sorry. First drag the file, then hold Alt before you release it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open Nautilus
2. Got to 'file' - 'Scripts' - 'Create Launcher'
3. Choose type and choose application type, fill in name (what you want to call it), command (how to run it) and comment (if you want)
4. You can change the icon by clicking it and then choosing the appropriate icon

You'll find the launcher on your desktop